# _.each in BackboneJS

Tags: backbone.js

```
var MenuListView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el : '#menus',
            reset : function() {
                var hIndex = this.getTheMenuIndexHighlighting();
                _.each(this.model.models[hIndex].attributes.subMenus, function(model, index) {
                    model.set({highlight : false});
                });
    });
```

_.each not rotating in the above code.

**UPDATE**
here is how my submenu json

```
[ {title:'Applications',bmUrl:'',id:'1',subMenus:[ {title: 'MsWord', bmUrl : 'msword.com';, id: 1, subMenus: null}, {title: 'MsExcel', bmUrl : 'msexcel.com';, id: 2, subMenus: null}, {title: 'MsPP', bmUrl : 'mspp.com';, id: 3, subMenus: null}, {title: 'MsOneNote', bmUrl : 'msonenote.com';, id: 4, subMenus: null}, {title: 'MsOutlook', bmUrl : 'msoutlook.com';, id: 5, subMenus: null} ],imgUrl:''}]
```

Can any body tell me why?

Replacing _.each to $.each is rotating the loop but doesn't trigger the appropriate model view updating method.

Comment: What does the submenus look like?

Comment: [
        {title:'Applications',bmUrl:'',id:'1',subMenus:[
            {title: 'MsWord', bmUrl : 'http://msword.com', id: 1, subMenus: null},
            {title: 'MsExcel', bmUrl : 'http://msexcel.com', id: 2, subMenus: null},
            {title: 'MsPP', bmUrl : 'http://mspp.com', id: 3, subMenus: null},
            {title: 'MsOneNote', bmUrl : 'http://msonenote.com', id: 4, subMenus: null},
            {title: 'MsOutlook', bmUrl : 'http://msoutlook.com', id: 5, subMenus: null}
        ],imgUrl:''}]

Comment: Just for clarification, you posted the data for `this.model` or is that the data in `this.model.models[hIndex]`?

Comment: @jahir check our json using jsonlint.com

Comment: Can you give some more info on what `this.model` and `this.model.models` are? I believe something is wrong with how you handle models in backbone. Can you do a `console.log(this.model)` and post it?

Answer (score 2):

you should change this line

```
this.model.models[hIndex].attributes.subMenus
```

to

```
this.model.at(hIndex).get("subMenus")
```

EDIT:- by saying this i was assuming that subMenus in itself is a collection
but now it appears that its an array and going by the underscore site **_.each() isnt available for arrays** and only can be used on collections. where as jquerys each can be applied to arrays.
http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#arrays
link to underscore website notice that each isnt included for arrays

Comment: Underscore's each does iterate trough arrays. The very first example on the underscore website uses the each function on an array:
http://underscorejs.org/#each

However it is not a part of the array prototype.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly seems the answer will have to be put by guessing , because you posted a meager amount of code. But here is my try

- I think this should be
  `this.model.models[hIndex].attributes.subMenus` converted to `this.collection.models[hIndex].attributes.subMenus` assuming this.model refers to a collection which certainly has the models property.
- Second if you need model at a index there is [`at`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-at) method in collection thus simplifying to `this.collection.at(hIndex).attributes,subMenus`
- third since we use collection (referring to subMenus) you could do this now `this.collection.at(hIndex).get("subMenus").each(function(subMenu){alert(subMenu.toJSON());})`

your final code must be ( with loads of assumptions)

```
var MenuListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#menus',
    reset: function () {
        var hIndex = this.getTheMenuIndexHighlighting();
        this.collection.at(hIndex).get("subMenus").each(function (subMenu) {
            alert(subMenu.toJSON());
        })
    });
```

#### Update

Since you still seem to be noob to BBjs world. Create a view instance like below and you will have the above code work like jiffy

`var viewInstance = new MenuListView({collection:Menu})`

where Menu is the instance(`new`) of Collection (which you use)

Comment: this.collection is undefined.

Comment: @jahirhstu I did make a point that i assumed `model` is `collection` here that means while creating view do this `new viewInstance({collection:Menu});`

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed this.model.models[hIndex].attributes.subMenus  to this.model.at(hIndex).get('subMenus') and it worked. But i am not sure why my code didn't work. If you please explain.

Comment: @jahirhstu see my updated answer, Your code seems just correct but i can't confirm unless i see Big picture( all of your code)